# Pandas series of times, must convert to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Looks like this

```
  time
0   10
1 2321
2  845
```

I need to convert these to datetime. I've tried

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%H%M')
```

But it gives "time data 10 does not match format '%H%M' (match)"

Thanks

Output expected

```
  time
0 00:10
1 23:21
2 08:45
```

I need these as datetimes so I can make bins for each hour i.e.

```
    time   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ... 23
 0  00:10  1
 1  23:21                                  1
 2  08:45                          1
```

Comment: What would be your expected output? Is `24:50` actually `00:50` ?

Comment: I messed up, it actually displays early morning as single digits, i.e 00:05 is just 5

Comment: Please post the expected output for your example.

Comment: Done, per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit, I believe you need

```
pd.to_datetime(('00' + df.time.astype(str)).str[-4:], format='%H%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ser = pd.Series([10,2321,845]
print(ser)
0      10
1    2321
2     845
dtype: int64
```

Convert integers to 0 pre-padded format, then convert to date time.

```
print(pd.to_datetime(ser.apply(lambda x: '{0:0>4}'.format(x)), format='%H%M').dt.strftime("%H:%M"))

0    00:10
1    23:21
2    08:45
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(df.time.astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')

0    00:10
1    23:21
2    08:45
Name: time, dtype: object
```

To demonstrate *why* this works:

```
df.time.astype(str).str.zfill(4)

0    0010
1    2321
2    0845
Name: time, dtype: object
```

`zfill` will pad your times if needed with zeros, allowing you to cast to datetime cleanly.

To get your final desired output, you can use `Categorical` with `get_dummies`:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.time.astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
categories = pd.Categorical(values=s.dt.hour, categories=np.arange(24))

pd.get_dummies(categories)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```